# drag and drop column feature in JasperReports

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

Is there any option in *JasperReports* reporting tools to drag and drop column and generate report at run time?

Comment: Are you talking about *JasperReports Server*?

Comment: [Getting Started with JasperReports Server](https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/getting-started-jasperreports-server)

Comment: @AlexK : yes , I am talking about jasper report server . I am looking for some mechanism where I can drag and drop columns from a table and generate report at run time